# Hide gpg passphrase from process list

Tags: security, shell, encryption, script, gnupg

I have made a script that lets me edit gpg encrypted files in vim:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read_password() {
    printf "Enter passphrase: "
    stty -echo
    read password
    stty echo
    echo
}

usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "gpg-edit [-s/-a] [FILE]"
    echo "-a    asymmetric encryption"
    echo "-s    symmetric encryption"
}

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    usage
    exit
else
    file="$2"
    if [ ! -f $file ]; then
        echo "No such file, exiting"
        exit
    fi
    if [ "$1" != "-s" ] && [ "$1" != "-a" ]; then
        usage
        exit
    fi
fi

if [ -z "$EDITOR" ]; then
    editor="vim"
else
    editor=$EDITOR
fi

tmp_file="$(mktemp)"

if [ "$1" = "-a" ]; then
    gpg -d --yes -o "$tmp_file" "$file"
elif [ "$1" = "-s" ]; then
    read_password
    echo "$password" | gpg -d --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --batch -o "$tmp_file" "$file"
fi

gpg_exit=$?

if [ $gpg_exit -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Decryption failed, exiting"
    rm $tmp_file
    exit
fi

original_mod_time=$(stat -c %Y "$tmp_file")

$editor "$tmp_file"

new_mod_time=$(stat -c %Y "$tmp_file")

if [ "$original_mod_time" -ne "$new_mod_time" ]; then
    if [ "$1" = "-a" ]; then
        gpg -o "$file" -e --yes -r recipient "$tmp_file"
    elif [ "$1" = "-s" ]; then
        echo "$password" | gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --batch -o "$file" "$tmp_file"
    fi

    gpg_exit=$?

    if [ $gpg_exit -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Encryption failed, exiting"
    fi
fi

shred -u "$tmp_file"
```

However, it is insecure because `echo "$password"` will show the password
in the process list (for example when you run htop). How can I prevent this? I
would prefer if it would run in a POSIX compliant shell like `dash`. I know
I wouldn't have this issue if I didn't store the password in a variable and
just provide it directly to gpg, but then the user would have to type the
password three times in total in the case for symmetric encryption.

Comment: 1) Have you _observed_ `echo` in the process list, or is this just a preemptive worry? (Does it show up in forkstat or execsnoop, for example?) Even in dash, 'echo' is a shell built-in that doesn't _normally_ cause a separate executable to be run.

Comment: 2) Is dash support a strict requirement? You're already relying on `stat -c` and `shred` which are GNU Coreutils-specific, and a base POSIX system isn't guaranteed to have them; overall it's probably _more likely_ that a system would have Bash (or even Python) than GNU-compatible stat/shred.

Comment: 3) If you trust the HDD containing `/tmp` with the decrypted file, would it be an option to store the passphrase in the same location?